# Find the minimum positive integer $n$ and the matrix $A^{2020}$

Tags: matrices

Let $A=a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ $(a>0)$ and $I=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ satisfy $A^4+I=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

1. Find $a$ For this I can do. I saw $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
2. Find the minimum positive integer $n$ such that $A^n\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$
3. Find $A^{2020}$

---

So please help to tell me about this 2 and 3. Give me some hints or ideas!!

Comment: @BenGrossmann The problem statement says $a>0$.

Comment: Yeah but for $a>0$

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, missed that

Comment: Is this a challenge question?  Featuring the year number suggests that it might be.

Comment: @badjohn no it’s just sample question.

Comment: Sample questions are often for previous years so I don't get suspicious if I see 2019 or less.

Comment: @badjohn for the real sample it was 2014

Answer (score 1):

$1$. $A^4=-I\Rightarrow \hat i\rightarrow-\hat i,\hat j\rightarrow-\hat j\Rightarrow A$ is an anti-clockwise rotation matrix with $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$.

> Normalize $A$ by choosing $a=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ so that applying $A$
> - once results in an anti-clockwise rotation of $\frac{\pi}4$ and $\hat i\rightarrow \frac1{\sqrt 2}(\hat i+\hat j),\hat j\rightarrow \frac1{\sqrt 2}(-\hat i+\hat j)$,
> - four times results in an anti-clockwise rotation of $\pi$ and $\hat i\rightarrow-\hat i,\hat j\rightarrow -\hat j$. Note that $a=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$ also does the job, but $a>0$ is given (Reason why $A$ rotates anti-clockwise).

$2$. How many such rotations are required to turn $\hat j$ to $\hat i$?

> $n$ is the minimum positive integer multiple of $\frac{3\pi/2}{\pi/4}=6\Rightarrow n=6$.

$3.$ $A^{2020}$ is an anti-clockwise rotation matrix that turns $\hat i\rightarrow-\hat i,\hat j\rightarrow-\hat j$ because $2020\cdot \frac{\pi}4=505\pi=2n\pi+\pi$.

> $A^{2020}=-I$.

Comment: Can you explain me about this or do it more than this ?

Comment: @PetterGreen I have added some spoilers.

Comment: @Baheti ok thank for your helping.

Comment: @PetterGreen If you think an answer helped, perhaps you can approve it.

Answer (score 1):

For 2: $A^{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
0
\end{array}\right)$, so$$A^6\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)=-A^2\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right).$$Hint for 3: $2020$ is an odd multiple of $4$.

Comment: Can you give more about 2?

Comment: @PetterGreen If I did, it'd be more than a hint.

Comment: Ok please kindly

Comment: @PetterGreen See edit.